# Linux, Ubuntu adobe air issue

Tags: ubuntu, adobe-air

I am running one Album sample for our project demo. Using adobe flash builder 4.6. Finally I am converting to .air application to show the demo easily. The problem is application is working fine in my local system but not in the client system.

We both are using the same version of latest software

Adobe flash player -11
Adobe air - 3.1

But in the client system all the menus are disabled. But its working fine in my system. Can you help me out where I'm struck..

So I am trying to show the demo from server

I have installed adobe air in my linux server

How to run my application ?

I have placed my application under /var/www

How to pass the link to the client because it is not a html file. I am little bit confused on that

waiting for ur reply

Comment: How's your app getting info for menus? Where from?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning June 14 2011, Adobe AIR is no longer supported for desktop Linux distributions. Users can install and run AIR 2.6 and earlier applications but can't install or update to AIR 2.7. The last version to support desktop Linux distributions is AIR 2.6.

You can get Adobe AIR 2.6 [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html).

Read more [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/install-air-2-64-bit.html).

Comment: and you'll see here: https://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb11-12.html that 2.6 is critically vulnerable and shouldn't be used.  They leave linux users with no good option :(